# Retornar valor de un DropDownList en webforms asp 3 capas

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Bueno mi problema es que independiente del ítem que seleccione en el dropdownlist me retorna 0 o el nombre contenido en ese indice en el único momento que me devuelve otro valor es cundo lo dejo en la opción de "seleccione un proveedor" y es por esto que no puedo realizar el registro del curso.
A continuación dejo el código:

**En mi capa de presentación tengo esto:**

```html
<div class="form-group">  
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" class="control-label col-md-2" runat="server" Text="Proveedor:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProveedor" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

**en el code-behind:**

> 

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                cargarLista();
            }
        }

        public void cargarLista()
        {

            ProveedorBL a = new ProveedorBL();
            List<ProveedorBL> lstProveedores = a.obtenerProveedores();

            Carga(lstProveedores, this.ddlProveedor, "id_proveedor", "nombre_proveedor");

        }

        public static void Carga(object coleccion, DropDownList combo, string pDataValueField, string pDataTextField)
        {
            try
            {
                combo.Items.Clear();
                combo.DataValueField = pDataValueField;
                combo.DataTextField = pDataTextField;
                combo.DataSource = coleccion;
                combo.DataBind();
                combo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccione un proveedor", "-1"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nombre = this.txtNombre.Text;
            string lugar = this.txtLugar.Text;
            DateTime fecha_inicio = DateTime.Parse(fechaInicio.Value);
            DateTime fecha_termino = DateTime.Parse(fechaTermino.Value);
            DateTime fecha_es = DateTime.Parse(eSatisfaccion.Value);
            DateTime fecha_et = DateTime.Parse(eTransferencia.Value);
            string tipo = this.rblFinanciada.SelectedValue;
            int id_proveedor = int.Parse(ddlProveedor.SelectedItem.Value);
            ProveedorBL proveedor = new ProveedorBL();
            ProveedorBL x = proveedor.buscarProveedor(id_proveedor);

            CursoBL nuevo = new CursoBL()
            {
                nombre_curso = nombre,
                fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio,
                fecha_termino = fecha_termino,
                fecha_encuestaS = fecha_es,
                fecha_encuestaT = fecha_et,
                lugar = lugar,
                tipo = tipo,
                proveedor = x
            };

            nuevo.agregarCurso();
        }
```

Comment: que pasa si usas ddlProveedor.SelectedValue ?

Comment: ya encontré la solución en el string pDataValueField en vez del id_proveedor repito lo del string pDataTextField que es el nombre_proveedor ahí si me devuelve el ítem seleccionado, gracias de todas maneras.